# CPU bound and I/O bound graph algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph, io, cpu, bounds

I'm trying to find some examples of CPU bound graph algorithms, but I can't find any example with a fair explanation of why it is CPU bound.

The same thing for I/O bound graph algorithms. I know that PageRank is an example of this last one, but I'm not really sure why.

Comment: It depends on the size of the graph, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

Except for special cases, finding [a proper edge-coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring) for a graph is known to be [NP-complete](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0210055).

Comment: The question asks about CPU-bound and IO-bound graph applications.